# What should I do to change the contents of the modal according to the contents of the carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want the data of the title to appear in the modal window when I click the 'Open Modal' button in the Carousel. But the way I implemented it is that all Carousel title data is in one modal window.

If I click the 'Open Modal' button, how can I make sure that only those titles, not all titles of Carousel, enter the modal window?

For example, if you click the 'Open Modal' button in the 'Exercise App' Carousel, only the words 'Exercise App' should appear in the modal window.

P.S. I use 'chakra ui'

-Modal components-

```
const CarouselModal = (props: any) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>this</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarouselModal;
```

-Carousel components-

```
        {cards.map((card, index) => (
          <Box
            key={index}
            height={"6xl"}
            position="relative"
            backgroundPosition="center"
            backgroundRepeat="no-repeat"
            backgroundSize="cover"
            backgroundImage={`url(${card.image})`}
          >
            <Container size="container.lg" height="600px" position="relative">
              <Stack
                spacing={6}
                w={"full"}
                maxW={"lg"}
                position="absolute"
                top="50%"
                transform="translate(0, -50%)"
              >
                <Heading
                  fontSize={{ base: "3xl", md: "4xl", lg: "5xl" }}
                  color="white"
                >
                  <Contain>{card.title}</Contain>
                </Heading>
                <Contain>
                  <Text
                    fontSize={{ base: "3xl", lg: "lg" }}
                    color="white"
                    fontWeight="bolder"
                  >
                    {card.text}
                    <br />
                    {card.TechnologyStackText}
                    <br />
                  </Text>
                  <ModalContain>
                    <CarouselModal />
                  </ModalContain>
                </Contain>
              </Stack>
            </Container>
          </Box>
        ))}
```

Comment: What does "Now all the titles are written in phrases" mean? Are you referring to the titles here `<ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>`? What do you *want* rendered as the modal title, `card.title`?

Comment: I want the 'card.title' data of '<Contain>{card.title}</Contain>' to come from '<ModalHeader>ModalTitle</ModalHeader>' instead of 'this'.

Comment: The phrase "Now all the titles are written in prases" was deleted because it could be misleading.

Comment: In other words, I would like to have 'card.title' in 'ModalBody' this</ModalBody>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `card.title` value as a prop to the `CarouselModal` component.

Example:

```
<ModalContain>
  <CarouselModal title={card.title} />
</ModalContain>
```

Then reference the `props.title` in the modal component.

```
const CarouselModal = ({ title }: { title: string }) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>{title}</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! However, only the data values in the last array will be exposed in the modal window. May I know why?

Comment: @한대현 Modal components often render a single component into a React portal. I see it a lot when rendering an array of elements that trigger a modal that the last mapped array element is the content you see in the modal. This sounds similar to what you describe. The fix is to refactor the code a bit so each element has the button and passes it's content to a single modal component that is being rendered *outside* the array.

Comment: @한대현 If you wanted to provide a more complete [mcve] that included the imports and example data being mapped, and that `useDisclosure` hook code, I could make a suggested refactor. Otherwise, if you are satisfied with this answer as-is, welcome and cheers.